# Saving order information to two tables - angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm trying to save order information to two tables (many to many):

Example:

```
order(order_id, client_name)
1, Jonny
2, Tom

order_product(order_id, product_id, amount)
1, 3, 1
1, 4, 1
1, 5, 2
2, 3, 2
```

Currently, I can only save information to 'order' table.

I suppose I should save data to 'order' table and 'order_product' table in one angular method to avoid data inconsistency.

My angular service method:

```
  saveOrder(order: Order, orderedProducts: Array<Cart>): Observable<Order> {
    return this.httpClient.post<Order>(`http://localhost:8080/api/order/`, order);
  }
```

How should I fix this method to save data to 'order_product' also?

Comment: this is not an Angular (front) problem, you should check the design of backend and data layer.

Comment: are your trying to call two http call in a single http service method?

Comment: yeah, is it possible? or I should have two separated methods?